# How to save a local copy of an older R package

Tags: r, rstudio

We have some legacy scripts that require an older version of the `srvyr` package.

Is there a way to store a local copy of the older package to make it easier for us to downgrade when needed for executing these scripts?

Comment: You can have a custom `.libPaths()` where you install the old version. Then just update your `.libPaths()` when you want to use that one. R will use the first version of the package it finds when searching your library paths.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called `pkglite` which may do what you're asking for.

> pkglite: A tool, grammar, and standard to represent and exchange R package source code as text files. Converts one or more source packages to a text file and restores the package structures from the file.

I have used this with the package `data.table` as an example.

Install the package from GitHub

```
remotes::install_github("Merck/pkglite")
library("pkglite")
# Example using pack/unpack
# Visit https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pkglite/pkglite.pdf
# For details
```

Output a package to a specified location using `collate` and `pack`

```
"package/path/data.table" %>%
  collate(file_default()) %>%
  pack(., output = "output/path/pkglite.txt")
```

Now `unpack` the package from the txt file and install

```
# Unpack
unpack(
  "output/path/pkglite.txt",
  output = "path/to/unpack/package/pkglite_test",
  install = T
)
```